# WSAECONNREFUSED: Connection Refused error in AIX server

Tags: telnet, aix, inetd

I'm seeing this `WSAECONNREFUSED: Connection Refused` error when i'm launching my Smarterm terminal emulation session on a IBM `AIX` server.

Not sure as to what could be the reason behind this. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Try other terminal-emulators, other protocols (ssh, telnet, rlogin), other client-computers... First of all, ask the local administrator for help.

Comment: That means that a client (socket) can't connect to the target server (socket) on the specified port (reasons can be a lot: the server is not listening, firewall, ...). I have no _Smarterm_ knowledge, but I find  strange the fact that the error is _Ms_ specific ([MSDN: `WSAECONNREFUSED`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681391(v=vs.85).aspx)).